# Adding attribute to BehaviorExtensionElement

Tags: wcf, configuration, wcf-configuration, servicebehavior

I'm adding a custom behaviorExtensionElement for WCF and want to add an attribute that can be read when the configured element is being read, e.g.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="myExtension"
             type="Bar.FooBarElement, Bar"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <myExtension myAttribute="Foo" />
```

However, I get an error "Unrecognized attribute 'myAttribute'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."

How can I avoid this? How do I read the myAttribute value in code?

Comment: described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty easy, since BehaviorExtensionElement subclasses ConfigurationElement, the usual configuration rules apply.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("myAttribute")]
public string MyAttribute
{
  get { return (string)this["myAttribute"]; }
  set { this["myAttribute"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the BehavoiorExtensionElement as an attribute in the Service Interface like:
[myExtension]
bool UpdateObject(object myObject); ?? Thanks a lot